# Random image on Revolution Slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have 5 possible images for the header of my WP home page.

But I display only one image.
I use revolution Slider to display it (nice text effects ...).

I would like to display randomly one of theses 5 images.
Is that possible ?

I can't find, either on Revolution Slider website, either on any forum how to display one single random image with Revolution Slider. I only found a script to randomize the order of multiple slides.

Thanx for your help.
M

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it works with Revolution Slider 6.

I wrote that in the custom JS editor associated with Slider Revolution :

```
const totalSlides = jQuery('rs-slide').size();
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalSlides);
for (let i = 0 ; i < totalSlides ; i++) {
    if (i !== randomIndex) {
      revapi1.revremoveslide(i);
    }
}
```